# Plotting multiple graphs with multiple points in one chart (Excel)

Tags: excel, graph, line

I am looking for some suggestions on plotting multiple graphs with multiple points in one single chart. I am not a statistics person and so I am unaware of what this graph is actually called.

Basically, I have 6 data series and I want to plot line graphs for each into one common graph.

My X-axis should only be 4 categorical variables/numbers 1, 2 , 3 and 4.

Now the catch is for each data series, every categorical variable of the X-axis has multiple points. Something like this :

```
(X,Y) = (1,43)
(X,Y) = (1,57)
(X,Y) = (1,86)
(X,Y) = (2,42)
(X,Y) = (2,63)
(X,Y) = (3,72)
(X,Y) = (3,82)
(X,Y) = (4,81)
```

This is for one data series. Similarly, I have 5 other data series which have something similar. Some data series may or may not have all 4 categorical variables 1,2,3 and 4. I want to plot all of them into one graph.

How should I go about plotting this graph, preferably in Excel ?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

because of your multiple x-points, I would say - not as a line graph ;)

but then again, you should aks yourself, what question shall my graph answer or which correllation should it illustrate.

I assume your data reflects some information you want to visualize. The question here is what this information is. Based on that you can choose a graph to support that. And for this graph you will need to provide your data, and might need to put it in an more appropriate form.

My guess right now, would be a point-graph.